# Creating a sequence to scrape text from url's using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to create some code to scrape the names of the officials that have officiated each NBA game in a season. All the url's I am trying to scrape from are similarly formatted, so I need some code that identifies the format and `reads` the official's names. Thank you very much for your help!

You will see that:

1. The first version of `# extract officials` below, reads the headings `inactive`, `officials`, `attendance`, etc.
2. The second version of `# extract officials` reads the text after each of the above mentioned headings.
3. I need some code that will recognize this format/pattern on multiple url's and read the official's names each time.

`Scott Foster`, `Ron Garretson`, `Dedric Taylor` in this particular url example:

```
# get webpage
url = paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/", "201810160BOS", ".html")
webpage = read_html(url)

# extract officials
data = webpage %>% 
    html_nodes(paste("body > div > div > div > div > strong")) %>%
    html_text()

# extract officials
data = webpage %>% 
    html_nodes(paste("body > div > div > div > div > a")) %>%
    html_text()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about R myself and I'm sure there is a better way, but perhaps this can be a start:

```
library(rvest)


url = paste0("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/", "201810160BOS", ".html")
webpage = read_html(url)

data = webpage %>% html_nodes(paste("body > div > div > div > div > a"))


urls <- data %>% html_attr("href")
text <- data %>% html_text()

df <- data.frame(urls, text, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

refs <- df[stringr::str_detect(urls, "referees"),"text"]
```

This is the result I get: from the above code:

> refs
>   [1] "Scott Foster"  "Ron Garretson" "Dedric Taylor"